# Select random with limit not always working

Tags: php, mysql, select, random, distinct

I got this mysql select from some post here in this site, and 99% of the time it works great, but sometimes it won't return the number of random elements I asked for, and I have no idea why. Here's a recent example that failed:

```
SELECT DISTINCT movie_title
FROM movies AS r1 JOIN
     (SELECT (RAND() * (SELECT MAX(movie_id) FROM movies)) AS id2
    ) AS r2
WHERE r1.movie_id >= r2.id2 AND movie_title != "New Moon"
ORDER BY r1.movie_id ASC LIMIT 4
```

The answer was this array: Array([0] => After Sex,[1] => New Moon)
Only two elements when it should have been four.

I'm using this on the quiz section of my movies site (http://www.crosstastemovies.com). The database table has around 1823 movies.
Can someone please shed some light on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not returning the right number because there are not enough rows.  When `rand()` returns a value very close to 1, the value of `id2` is very close to the maximum value.  There are not enough rows that satisfy the `where` clause, so all available are returned.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any other way to return the number of rows I want? 
Maybe changing RAND() or id2 if the value returned by RAND is very close to 1?...

Comment: I ended up verifying the array created. If the number of values are less than limit I just call it again. Not the ideal but works.